# Itunes wireless sync between iPad and Macbook Air

Tags: itunes, ipad, macbook-pro

Is there any way to iTunes sync an iPad with a MacBook Air using a wireless connection (either WiFi or bluetooth). If so, how?

I managed to bluetooth pair my MacBook Air with my iPad, but I can't see my iPad on iTunes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Apple support page: [iOS: How to transfer or sync content to your computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1296?viewlocale=en_US)

Syncing over Wi-Fi requires iTunes 10.5 or later and iOS 5 or later. Also, your computer must be connected to the same Wi-Fi network as your iOS device.

1. Open iTunes.
2. To set up Wi-Fi syncing, connect your iOS device to your computer with the included USB cable.
3. Click the device button in the upper right corner. (If you are viewing the iTunes Store, click the Library button in the upper right corner. The device button will then be visible.)
   In the Summary tab, select "Sync with this [device] over Wi-Fi".

[image: Sync via iPad]

4. Whenever the computer and the iOS device are on the same network, the iOS device will appear in iTunes, and you can sync it. The iOS device will sync automatically when all of the following are true:

   - The iOS device is plugged in to power
   - iTunes is open on the computer
   - The iOS device and the computer are on the same Wi-Fi network
5. While the iOS device appears in the upper right corner of iTunes, you can select the content tabs and configure sync options.
   Click Apply or Sync to sync the iOS device.